# Can my @InitiatingFlow be a Generic class?

Tags: corda

Is it possible to define an @InitiatingFlow as a generic class?:

```
@InitiatingFlow
public class FungibleStateIssueSend<T extends Oil> extends FlowLogic<SignedTransaction> {...}
```

...If I try I get a compile error on the @InitiatedBy annotation in the receiving flow:

```
@InitiatedBy(FungibleStateIssueSend.class)
public class FungibleStateIssueReceive extends FlowLogic<Void> {...}
```

Error:

```
Incompatible types. Found: 'java.lang.Class<com.template.flows.FungibleStateIssueSend>', required: 'java.lang.Class<? extends net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic<?>>'
```

Here is how I was going to use it:

```
// Define the delivery unit (bbl, m3 or tonne) and corresponding API of the oil in that unit:
WtiBbl wtiBbl = new WtiBbl(new BigDecimal("4.5"));

// Set Amount of units for delivery:
Amount<WtiBbl> amountWtiBbl = new Amount<>(1_000L, wtiBbl);

// Create a FungibleState so the delivery can be divided between different shippers:
OilFungibleState<WtiBbl> juneProduction = new OilFungibleState<>(Month.JUNE, Collections.singletonList(partyA), amountWtiBbl);

// Issue the FungibleState onto the ledger...
FungibleStateIssueSend<WtiBbl> fungibleStateIssueSend = new FungibleStateIssueSend<>(juneProduction);
CordaFuture<SignedTransaction> future = partyANode.startFlow(fungibleStateIssueSend);
mockNetwork.runNetwork();

SignedTransaction signedTransaction = future.get();
```

I can work around the limitation.  I just want to understand if this is a Corda thing or a Java thing?

Comment: Please share the full error stack.

Comment: @AdelRustum Compile Error:

error: incompatible types: Class<FungibleStateCreate> cannot be converted to Class<? extends FlowLogic<?>>

Comment: Can you update the question and add the part where you use/call `FungibleStateCreate`? I want to see how you're defining/using it.

Comment: @AdelRustum I've updated the question. I know other ways I can accomplish what I am trying to achieve overall.  This was just an error I ran into that I wasn't expecting and I'm trying to understand if it's a Corda limitation or maybe something I didn't know about java annotations (I'm pretty new in Java).

Comment: Honestly I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: @AdelRustum I appreciate your help – you are a real asset to the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels like its more of a Java thing.

For example, if I use a wild card for the class type it works fine with generic typed parameter.

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface TestAnnotation{
    public Class<?> value();
}
```

So I can use the annotation `@TestAnnotation(Initiator.class)` in a class, while Initiator could be defined as:

```
public static class Initiator<T> extends FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>
```

But when we bound the wildcard to something below, the compiler complains.

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface TestAnnotation{
    public Class<? extends FlowLogic<?>> value();
}
```

But if we remove the wildcard from the FlowLogic it works. Not sure why the compiler complains because of that wildcard.